# Is it possible to allow users to upload videos to my YouTube channel via my mobile app?

Tags: youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api, google-apis-explorer

Is it possible to allow users to upload videos to my YouTube channel via my mobile app, without allowing them access to manage my YouTube account?

Also, the uploaded video must not be public until i activate it.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines. Off-topic questions such as this are routinely closed, but if edited to ask an *answerable* question, can be re-opened again. Thanks.

Comment: Without storing your Youtube Login credentials within the app itself (which is a terrible idea), you would need to store them on the server. And then the users could use your app, upload to your server, and then upload from your server to youtube

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **No**. If you allow them to upload, you must also *at least* allow them to manage your account's videos (not just those they upload).

The YouTube API docs explain the [authorization scopes](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#auth) required to upload; the upload request requires authorization with at least one of the following scopes:

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl
```

[This page describes the permissions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#identify-access-scopes) available to each of these scopes. Here's a list of the scopes that allow uploading; you'll see they all allow management of videos/account details as well.

```
+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                      Scopes                       |                          Permissions                          |
+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload    | Manage your YouTube videos                                    |
| https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube           | Manage your YouTube account                                   |
| https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload    | Manage your YouTube videos                                    |
| https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner    | View and manage your assets and associated content on YouTube |
| https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl | Manage your YouTube account                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```